# Is there a trigonometric field which is different enough from real numbers?

Tags: fields, quadratic-forms

I found this topic in a book ['Metric Affine Geometry' by Ernst Snapper and Robert J. Troyer](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Metric_Affine_Geometry.html?id=PVbvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y).
I call a field $k$ trigonometric iff there is a quadratic form $q$ over $k^2$ such that every two lines through the origin in $k^2$ is isometric with respect to $q$. This condition is sufficient to introduce trigonometric functions over $\mathbf{SO}(k^2,q)$ in a geometric fashion. Hence, a name.

Obviously, $\mathbb{R}$ is trigonometric. I know, that to be trigonometric the field $k$ must be Pythagorean, that is for every finite sequence of values $(\alpha_i)^n_{i=1} \in k^n$ there is a $\gamma \in k$ such that
$$
 \sum^n_{i=1} \alpha_i^2 = \gamma^2,
$$

namely every sum of squares is a square. Secondly it must be a formally real field, which means that $-1$ is not a sum of  squares. Hence, sadly $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}(x),\mathbb{Q}_p,\mathbb{F}_p$ are all not trigonometric. Probably some extension of $\mathbb{R}(x)$ which allows square roots of formally positive functions may work. But I still doubt that it can be totally-ordered, and probably there are some clews in differential Galois theory. Maybe $\hat{\mathbb{Q}} \cap \mathbb{R}$, where $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$ are algebraic numbers will work, or just adjoining enough real algebraic square roots to $\mathbb{Q}$ (call it a Pythagorean closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$). At least it is Pythagorean and formally real. But I don't think it is interesting enough.

But I'm very a curious about finding an interesting example of trigonometric field different from $\mathbb{R}$. Trigonometric field $k$ different from $\mathbb{R}$ may mean formally that $k$ is not between $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.  I would be very grateful if you could suggest one.
If the result are negative, this would mean that class of all trigonometric fields has certain lower and upper bounds.

Comment: I would look for: (1) Puiseux series or (2) Levi-Civita field or (3) Hahn series.  These are real-closed ordered fields larger than $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Any real closed field (for example Puiseux series) is trigonometric, and likely to contain subfields which are not real closed but still trigonometric. I don't know whether they qualify as "interesting enough" though.

Comment: @ReidBarton Thank you. This is surely interesting enough.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar  Thanks! Those are clearly constructions I need to pay more attention to.

Comment: The reason I suggested real closed fields might not be that interesting is that maybe the easiest way to see that they are trigonometric is to observe that being a trigonometric field is a first-order condition in the language of fields, and real closed fields satisfy all the same such conditions as the reals do! So as far as first-order properties are concerned, nothing new happens in these real closed fields.

Comment: @ReidBarton I never thought this way.  But if field is trigonometric, then it must be formally real, so it has to be contained in a real closed field. So maybe studying real closed field is not such a bad place to start, as over trigonometric fields can be then studied as restrictions of corresponding real closed structures to certain subsets? Moreover, as most of those field not even locally compact, there must be some distinctions at least in analytic or geometric properties of corresponding trigonometric construction. I don't think that Puiseux-series-valued $\cos$ would be the same.

Comment: An ordered field in which every positive element has a square root is trigonometric (using the standard scalar product). This is usually far from real-closed (e.g., the subset of $\mathbf{R}$ generated from rational by field operations and taking square roots of positive elements).

Comment: @YCor you are right. But I still can't see why fields generated like you say are more interesting than real-closed. Any real-closed field probably have many subfields like these.

Comment: I didn't say they're more/less interesting. Real-closed field are the most trivial examples (since as said by Reid Barton it's a 1st order property), which is already sufficient to provide examples of arbitrary infinite cardinal. The question is maybe to just formulate a simple necessary and sufficient condition for a field (not in terms of quadratic forms!) to satisfy the property.

Comment: @YCor Ok. It seems that any ordered Pythagorean field $k$ would be trigonometric. Take any basis $e$ of $k^2$ and define quadratic form so it has matrix $I$ in $e$. Then any vector $v = \alpha e_1 + \beta e_2$, so $\| v \|^2 = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 = \gamma^2$ as $k$ is Pythagorean. Then $v$ can be 're-normalized', so corresponding norm is 1 if $\gamma \neq 0$. But as $k$ is ordered $\gamma^2 > 0$ as non-zero squares must be positive in an ordered field. Now it is qa problem to find trigonometric fields with quadratic form which are not like $I$ or $-I$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A field $K$ is trigonometric iff the sum of 2 squares is a square and $-1$ is not a square (equivalently, the set of nonzero squares is stable under addition), in which case the standard scalar product on $K^2$ satisfies the required condition.

Indeed, suppose that $K$ is trigonometric, so there is a *nonzero* quadratic form $q$ on $K^2$ such that $\mathrm{O}(q)$ is transitive on $\mathbf{P}^1(K)$ (if $q=0$ is allowed the condition is void! if nonzero, the kernel is invariant by the isometry group, so has to be reduced to $\{0\}$, i.e. $q$ is nondegenerate). Up tp rescale $q$ and change basis, we can suppose that $q(x,y)=x^2+ty^2$ for some $t\in K$. Transitivity of $\mathrm{O}(q)$ implies that $q(x,y)$ is nonzero for all nonzero $(x,y)$, and that $q(x,y)/q(x',y')$ is a square for all nonzero $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$. Applying this to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ already implies that $t$ is a square, and hence after again changing the basis, we can suppose that $t=1$.

Since $q(x,y)/q(1,0)$ is a square for all $x,y$, we obtain that $x^2+y^2$ is a square for all $x,y$. If $-1$ were a square, say $i^2=-1$, the element $(1,i)$ would have $q(1,i)=0$, contradiction.

Conversely (the converse is already in the comments), suppose that the conditions are satisfied, and fix the standard scalar product. Consider $(a,b)\neq (0,0)$. Since $a^2+b^2$ is a square, we can rescale it to assume $a^2+b^2=1$, and then it is in the orbit of $(1,0)$, using the rotation matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$.

(Note that the proof also implies that if a 2-dimensional quadratic form $q$ has $\mathrm{O}(q)$ transitive on $\mathbf{P}^1(K)$, then $q$ is equivalent to a scalar multiple of the usual scalar product.)

---

(Added) Examples:

- real-closed fields;
- more generally, fields for which $x\le y$ $\Leftrightarrow$ y-x is a square defines a total order. The smallest subfield of $\mathbf{R}$ among those stable under taking square roots of positive elements has this property, yet isn't real-closed;
- there are more examples, namely it can happen that there are elements $y$ such that neither $y$ nor $-y$ is a square. This is for instance the case for the ring $\mathbf{R}(\!(t)\!)$. Indeed, in this field, the nonzero squares are the elements of the form $t^{2n}P$ where $P\in\mathbf{R}[\![t]\!]$ has $P(0)>0$ and $n\in\mathbf{Z}$. In this field, none of $\pm t$ is a square.

Comment: @NikPronko yes, I should have said up to rescaling. It's fixed now;